# Update merge in pyspark takes very long

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake, upsert

Why does the MERGE INTO statement take significantly longer to update records in the old DataFrame when the old DataFrame has over 200 columns compared to when the old DataFrame has only 5 columns? What factors contribute to this performance disparity, and how can it be optimized for wide old DataFrames? I am working with Delta table in Databricks and following code is used:

```
# Register the DataFrames as temporary views
old.createOrReplaceTempView("old") #has 200+ columns
new.createOrReplaceTempView("new")

# Define and execute the MERGE statement
merge_sql = """
    MERGE INTO old
    USING new
    ON old.unique_id = new.unique_id
    AND old._PROC_END_DTS IS NULL
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        old._PROC_END_DTS = new._PROC_END_DTS,
        old._PROC_REC_DELETED = new._PROC_REC_DELETED
"""

spark.sql(merge_sql)
```

Note: the new table is very small

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the performance for wide old DataFrames consider the below

- As you are working with Delta tables, you can use of Delta Lake features like `Z-Ordering` help you improve query performance by organizing data efficiently.
- Consider partitioning on the **unique_id** column.

Know more about the [Z-ordering](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/data-skipping.html#what-is-z-ordering)

For example I have tried the below approach:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, BooleanType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MergeExample").getOrCreate()
data = [
    (1, None, False),
    (2, None, False),
    (3, None, False),
    (4, None, False)
]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("unique_id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("_PROC_END_DTS", StringType()),
    StructField("_PROC_REC_DELETED", BooleanType())
])
old_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
new_data = [
    (2, '2023-09-25', True),
    (3, '2023-09-26', True),
    (4, '2023-09-27', True),
    (5, '2023-09-28', True)
]
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_data, schema=schema)

old_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").partitionBy("unique_id").option("zorderCol", "unique_id").save("/FileStore/tables/old_01")
new_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").partitionBy("unique_id").option("zorderCol", "unique_id").save("/FileStore/tables/new_01")
merge_sql = """
    MERGE INTO delta.`/FileStore/tables/old_01` AS old
    USING delta.`/FileStore/tables/new_01` AS new
    ON old.unique_id = new.unique_id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        old._PROC_END_DTS = new._PROC_END_DTS,
        old._PROC_REC_DELETED = new._PROC_REC_DELETED
"""
spark.sql(merge_sql)
result_df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/FileStore/tables/old_01")
result_df.show()
```

[image]

writing to the '**old**' and '**new**' DataFrames as Delta tables with options for overwriting data if the tables already exist.
partitioning the data by the **unique_id** column, and specifying a `Z-Order` column for optimization.

**Merge statement:**

**SQL MERGE** statement that merges data from the 'new' DataFrame into the 'old' DataFrame based on matching unique_id values.
When a match is found, it updates the columns _PROC_END_DTS and _PROC_REC_DELETED in the 'old' DataFrame with values from the 'new' DataFrame.

As you mentioned that performance issues for MERGE INTO statement when updating records in the old DataFrame with over 200 columns compared to when it has only 5 columns.
the reason if the old DataFrame has more indexes it may take longer to update records.